# Mathematica: How to combine lists of unequal length into single data structure

Tags: list, concatenation, wolfram-mathematica

I have multiple lists, for instance:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

I would like to combine these lists so that I can export a datafile of the following format:

```
a, b
1, 4
2, 5
3, 6
 , 7
 , 8
```

I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: raggedTranspose[v1_, v2_] := Transpose[{Join[v1, Table["", {Max[0, Length[v2] - Length[v1]]}]], Join[v2, Table["", {Max[0, Length[v1] - Length[v2]]}]]}]; a={1,2,3}; b={4,5,6,7,8}; raggedTranspose[a, b] gives you {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {"", 7}, {"", 8}}.  Study that, take it apart. Figure out exactly how it works.

Comment: Check out `Flatten`. Among its many uses, it can transpose a ragged array. `Flatten[{a, b}, {{2}, {1}}]` gives `{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {7}, {8}}`

Comment: I've found a few ways of doing it using both of your suggestions.. thank you.